# How to create a new entry in mongoDB if it does not exist?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on a website where the user can add data for accidents of a particular year. What I want is that If the user tries to add data for a new year that doesn't exist in the DB then the code should create a new entry for that year. This is a compressed form of the schema I am using

```
    const yearSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  year: Number,
  sheet1: {
    f_jan_acc: Number,
    gi_jan_acc: Number,
    mi_jan_acc: Number,
    ni_jan_acc: Number,
    tot_jan_acc: Number,}
    })
```

Let's say that entry for the year 2021 exists but doesn't exist for 2022. Now if the user tries to add data for the year 2022 , the code should create a new entry for the year 2022.
This is what I have been trying so far:

```
Year.find({ year: 2022 } , function(err ,found){
    if(err){
      console.log(err)
    }
    else{
      if(found){
        console.log(found)
      }
      else{
        const newYear = new Year({
          year : 2022,
        })
        newYear.save()
      }
    }
  });
```

What else can I try or perhaps even improve this one?
Thanks for the help

Comment: I'm trying to find an example, but the pattern is called "upsert" (update if you can't insert). Or do you want nothing to happen if it exists?

Comment: @zero298 "update if you can't insert" - it's the other way around, though. :) "update record. If not found, insert one"

Comment: @zero298 my code worked with a few adjustments